# export mongo database connection to models.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');


var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/database_name');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use(require('./routes/index'));
app.use(require('./routes/page1'));
app.use(require('./routes/page2'));
app.use(require('./routes/page3'));
app.use(require('./routes/page4'));

exports.conn = conn;

app.listen(3000,function(request, response){
    console.log("Server is running at Port 3000");
});
```

models.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = require('./app');

var conn = app.conn

module.exports.User = conn.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
}));
```

On running `node app.js`, i am getting an error that  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined`.
app.js and models.js are in the same folder.

P.S. i am using createConnection function because i have to make two database connections.

Comment: What is the `conn` you are requiring in the `models.js`? Do you try to use the variable `conn` from the `app.js` like this? This is not how node.js works. `require('conn')` will look into `node_modules` for a package named `conn`.

Comment: oh God...yes...sorry for that...my bad...but still the problem persist.
conn is the mongodb connection created by createConnection function. I want to use this variable (conn) in another file(models.js)

Comment: @migg: i have modified the code for exporting variable. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not require `app.js` inside a module. That defeats the purpose. Either use a separate module that handles the connection, or use dependency injection like this:

### models.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(conn) { // inject connection
    return {
        User: conn.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
            username: String,
            password: String,
        })
    };
}
```

### app.js

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/database_name');

var models = require('./models')(conn);

models.User(...) // do stuff with User function
```

This is better structured, more maintainable and better testable as you can inject a mock for `conn`.

Answer (score 0):

finally figured it out:

to make it globally available we need to replace following line

```
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/database_name');
```

with

```
module.exports.conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/database_name');
```

Comment: Yes you can do that but you should not.

Comment: why not? i can put connection code in a separate file and not in app.js?